# Change UIFont in secure UITextField strange behaviour in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, passwords, ios7, uitextfield

I create a simple project: https://github.com/edzio27/textFieldExample.git

where I add two `UITextField`s, one with login and second one with secure password. I've noticed there strange behaviour:

1. click on login and add some text,
2. click on password and add some text,
3. click again to login `UITextField`

[image]

Notice that there is a strange behaviour in password font size. It is only appears in iOS7.

What can be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I am experiencing the same behavior, however when I go back and reselect the password field the font size changes back to the smaller size. So basically, when the field is selected the font is smaller, when another field is selected the font is larger.

Comment: It happens to me as well. It seems to behave badly when I use the custom font

Comment: Ok, for me the problem was actually the custom font itself which doesn't have a proper "password dot" char, but much smaller than standard helvetica

Comment: @bettola how did you fix it? use a different font?

Comment: @bettola gotcha. I figured out a workaround that works well for my situation and allows me to keep using my custom font. Added as answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As a couple people pointed out, it appears secure text fields don't always play well with custom fonts. I worked around this by using the UITextField's `UIControlEventEditingChanged` to monitor for changes to the textfield and set it to the system font (with the normal looking bullet points) when anything is entered, else use my custom font.

This allows me to keep using my custom font for the textfield placeholder and still look good when the password is entered. The characters that show one-at-a-time while being entered will be the system font, but I'm okay with that.

In viewDidLoad:

```
[self.passwordTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Now add a textFieldDidChange method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(id)sender
{
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)sender;

    if (textField == self.passwordTextField) {
        // Set to custom font if the textfield is cleared, else set it to system font
        // This is a workaround because secure text fields don't play well with custom fonts
        if (textField.text.length == 0) {
            textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:textField.font.pointSize];
        }
        else {
            textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:textField.font.pointSize];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Toggling secure/insecure state with a custom font: to show 'secure' text (blob characters), a font containing the blob character is set by iOS. This is the font you're later seeing render text when you switch to insecure mode.

Though the textfield keeps your assigned custom font, the field's content is an attributed string which references the blob-containing font.

**The simple solution**: write to the attributed string field, and your correct, custom font is re-applied.

To turn off secure entry & keep a custom font:

```
passwordTextField.secureTextEntry = false

// We have to remove iOS' secure font by setting attributedText.
let pwd = passwordTextField.text!
passwordTextField.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: pwd)
```

Comment: Indeed the cleaner solution of all. And the most acute.

Answer (score 4):

If you turn off "Adjust to Fit" in the password field it will stop doing that resize when you resign the responder.

Comment: doesnt work for me either. I believe it to be a custom font issue, as I'm also using custom fonts

Comment: Custom fonts sometimes have really funny baselines. the issue I solved here was only for the project he linked. As for custom fonts its always a bit :/ when dealing with iOS.

Comment: it worked for first toggle between secure text entry = true and false but didn't work later

Answer (score 1):

Set your delegate of your TextField and add this;

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (!textField.secureTextEntry) {
        return YES;
    }

    textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if (textField.text.length > 0) {
        textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0f];
    } else {
        textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"YourFont" size:18.0f];
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this: 
[UITextField secureTextEntry bullets with a custom font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969451/uitextfield-securetextentry-bullets-with-a-custom-font)

There is an elegant solution by [glyuck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783142/glyuck) which I liked. 
http://github.com/elegion/ELFixSecureTextFieldFont
He created a category on UITextField. To have nicely displayed dots you have to include 
ELFixSecureTextFieldFont.h and .m files and then call - (void)fixSecureTextFieldFont on your textField once like this:

```
[yourCustomSecureTextField fixSecureTextFieldFont];
```

That is it.