# Why does the font on iOS textfields changes upon altering secureTextEntry programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

When changing the value of secureTextEntry on a UITextField the font changes. Does anybody know why and how to change this behaviour or how to work around it?
No custom fonts involved, only system font.

[image: Gif of problem in action]

Code:

```
let image: UIImage?
if self.passwordField.secureTextEntry == true {
    let content = self.passwordField.text
    self.passwordField.secureTextEntry = false
    [...]
} else {
    self.passwordField.secureTextEntry = true
    [...]
}
```

Dumped `self.passwordField.font` on changes and doesn't seem to be changed

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475918/change-uifont-in-secure-uitextfield-strange-behaviour-in-ios7

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/20969451/887210

Comment: I haven't tested it but this comment specifically addresses the font issue on toggling `secureTestEntry`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31811916/887210

Comment: Thanks Kenneth, that solution (resignFirstResponder)
worked.
Unfortunately I haven't found the first thread before, shame on me :(