# Strange Bug in Secure Textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

[image]

Hey! What is This? the text goes bottom when i click on email everytime as i am using custom font. Actually i have tried all available solution from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475918/change-uifont-in-secure-uitextfield-strange-behaviour-in-ios7) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969451/uitextfield-securetextentry-bullets-with-a-custom-font/20969693#20969693) and many more, Issue still not solved.
please guide me. Thank You

Comment: Hey! Same problem here

Comment: As mentioned in the linked answers, consider it a bug. However, it is not that easy for a secure textfield to place bullets correctly, when one uses a custom font. Obviously the calculation fails on some fonts giving strange results.